# How can I display my strings in a rectangle

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a secret message app by square code method, I need to get my string to form a near perfect square/rectangle (​r x c​) where ​c​ is the number of columns and ​r​ is the number of rows, such that ​c >= r​ and ​c - r <= 1​,

For instance

"If man was meant to stay on the ground, god would have given us roots."

is normalized to:

"ifmanwasmeanttostayonthegroundgodwouldhavegivenusroots"

and further organized in to a rectangle which is a function of the length.
The normalized text is 54 characters long, dictating a rectangle with ​c = 8 ​and ​r = 7​:

"ifmanwas"

"meanttos"

"tayonthe"

"groundgo"

"dwouldha"

"vegivenu"

"sroots "

### **Code:**

#### **JS:**

```
const text = document.querySelector('#normalized_text');
const string = document.querySelector('#message');
const error = document.querySelector('#alert');

const encodeMessage = () => {
  const message = string.value;
  
  function wordCount() {
    return message.split(" ").length;
  }
  
  function newMessage() {
    return message.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "").toLowerCase();
  }
  
  function rectangleSize() {
    return Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(newMessage.length));
  }  
 
  if(wordCount < 2 || message.length < 50) {
    error.innerHTML = "invalid message!";
    return false;
  }
  
  text.innerHTML = newMessage();
  return newMessage();
}
```

#### **HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type your secret message" id="message">
    <p id="alert"></p>
    <button type="button" class="button" onclick="encodeMessage()">Encode message</button>
</form>      
<div class="box">
    <h3>Normalised Text</h3>
    <p id="normalized_text"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

***edited after better understanding.

This will convert the string to lowercase, remove all characters that aren't `a-z` or `0-9`, and split the string into an array of chunks based on the square root of the normalized length.

You can then join this array and display in monospace font, and play with letter-spacing for a 'square' code feel.

```js
function Squarinize(content) {
  let normilized = content.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
  let columns = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(normilized.length));
  let square = [];
  for (i = 0; i < normilized.length; i += columns) {
    square.push(normilized.slice(i, i + columns));
  }
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = square.join('<br />');
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  Squarinize('test value')
}
```

```html
<div style="font-family: monospace; letter-spacing: 10px;" id="myDiv"></div>
```

result:

```
t e s
t v a
l u e
```